# Finding sum of elements in Swift array

Tags: arrays, swift

What is the easiest (best) way to find the sum of an array of integers in swift?
I have an array called multiples and I would like to know the sum of the multiples.

Answer (score 582, accepted):

This is the easiest/shortest method I can find.

Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
let multiples = [...]
let sum = multiples.reduce(0, +)
print("Sum of Array is : ", sum)
```

Swift 2:

```
let multiples = [...]
sum = multiples.reduce(0, combine: +)
```

---

Some more info:

This uses Array's reduce method (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_6reduceu__Rq_S__Fq_FzTqd__7combineFzTqd__qqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Element_qd___qd__)), which allows you to "reduce a collection of elements down to a single value by recursively applying the provided closure". We give it 0 as the initial value, and then, essentially, the closure `{ $0 + $1 }`. Of course, we can simplify that to a single plus sign, because that's how Swift rolls.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works great and I just want to add my example code with array of custom classes: `let totalSum = self.cheques.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount}`

Comment: Great answer but missing parameter name `combine`. Should be `multiples.reduce(0, combine: +)`.

Comment: What about the sum of elements in a multidimensional (say 2D or 3D) array?

Comment: Is it faster than a for loop?

Comment: @SwiftMatt Try using a `flatMap` on it first to flatten it to a single dimension array. `multiArray.flatMap{$0}.reduce(0, combine: +)`

Comment: @lorenzo - Testing on an iPhone 7 with latest Swift and XCode (a simple array filled with 1,000,000 UInt32 random values capped at 256 to prevent UInt32 overflow) interestingly shows the 'for' loop being just a hair faster (1.941 seconds versus 2.137 seconds), although that advantage is *not* present at 100,000 values (0.23 seconds each). IMHO, code clarity is worth any very minor performance cost here even when dealing with 32MB arrays.

Answer (score 142):

**Swift 3+** one liner to sum properties of objects

```
var totalSum = scaleData.map({$0.points}).reduce(0, +)
```

Where **points** is the property in my custom object **scaleData** that I am trying to reduce

Comment: This will unnecessarily iterate the whole collection twice

Comment: you can achieve this with `scaleData.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.points }`

Answer (score 55):

In **Swift 4** You can also constrain the sequence elements to [Numeric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) protocol to return the sum of all elements in the sequence as follow

```
extension Sequence where Element: Numeric {
    /// Returns the sum of all elements in the collection
    func sum() -> Element { return reduce(0, +) }
}
```

---

edit/update:

**Xcode 10.2 • Swift 5 or later**

We can simply constrain the sequence elements to the new [AdditiveArithmetic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic) protocol to return the sum of all elements in the collection

```
extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
    func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(.zero, +)
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

```
extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
    func sum() -> Element { reduce(.zero, +) }
}
```

---

```
let numbers = [1,2,3]
numbers.sum()    // 6

let doubles = [1.5, 2.7, 3.0]
doubles.sum()    // 7.2
```

To sum a property of a custom object we can extend Sequence to take a predicate to return a value that conforms to `AdditiveArithmetic`:

```
extension Sequence  {
    func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> T { reduce(.zero) { $0 + predicate($1) } }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
struct Product {
    let id: String
    let price: Decimal
}

let products: [Product] = [
    .init(id: "abc", price: 21.9),
    .init(id: "xyz", price: 19.7),
    .init(id: "jkl", price: 2.9)
]

products.sum(\.price)  // 44.5
```

Comment: Great, nice solution!

Comment: Best answer for me! 

Answer (score 31):

Swift3 has changed to :

```
let multiples = [...]
sum = multiples.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 4 example**

```
class Employee {
    var salary: Int =  0
    init (_ salary: Int){
        self.salary = salary
    }
}

let employees = [Employee(100),Employee(300),Employee(600)]
var sumSalary = employees.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.salary}) //1000
```

Comment: Very helpful because it includes an example of totaling an arithmetic property for an array of objects, which is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 13):

This also works:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var sumedArr = arr.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
print(sumedArr)
```

The result will be: 55

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3**

If you have an array of generic objects and you want to sum some object property then:

```
class A: NSObject {
    var value = 0
    init(value: Int) {
       self.value = value
    }
}

let array = [A(value: 2), A(value: 4)]      
let sum = array.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.value })
//                           ^       ^
//                        $0=result  $1=next A object
print(sum) // 6
```

Despite of the shorter form, many times you may prefer the classic for-cycle:

```
let array = [A(value: 2), A(value: 4)]
var sum = 0
array.forEach({ sum += $0.value}) 
// or
for element in array {
   sum += element.value
}
```

Comment: ciao Luca, here is my solution: array.map({$0.value}).reduce(0, +)

Comment: In this way you write more code and increment complexity.. so, why?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3, 4, and 5**

Using reduce:

`let totalAmount = yourTransactionsModelArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount}`

Old fashioned way for understanding purposes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 sum = sum + Int(multiples[i])!
}
```

//where n = number of elements in the array

Comment: Note that in Swift 3 this is no longer valid because the C style for loops have been removed from the language. Use for-in loops instead, Swift keeps track internally of the index.

Comment: That wouldn't work as it. You have to initialise sum to 0 first. The beauty of reduce is that it reminds you to think of the initial value.

Comment: `var sum = 0 ; for n in multiples {  sum += n }` although I would use reduce.

Comment: @naishta already mentioned that it the for loo she wrote is only for understanding purpose

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution: define a prefix operator for it.
Like the reduce "+/"  operator as in APL  (e.g. GNU APL)

A bit of a different approach here.

Using a protocol en generic type allows us to to use this operator on Double, Float and Int array types

```
protocol Number 
{
   func +(l: Self, r: Self) -> Self
   func -(l: Self, r: Self) -> Self
   func >(l: Self, r: Self) -> Bool
   func <(l: Self, r: Self) -> Bool
}

extension Double : Number {}
extension Float  : Number {}
extension Int    : Number {}

infix operator += {}

func += <T:Number> (inout left: T, right: T)
{
   left = left + right
}

prefix operator +/ {}

prefix func +/ <T:Number>(ar:[T]?) -> T?
{
    switch true
    {
    case ar == nil:
        return nil

    case ar!.isEmpty:
        return nil

    default:
        var result = ar![0]
        for n in 1..<ar!.count
        {
            result += ar![n]
        }
        return result
   }
}
```

use like so:

```
let nmbrs = [ 12.4, 35.6, 456.65, 43.45 ]
let intarr = [1, 34, 23, 54, 56, -67, 0, 44]

+/nmbrs     // 548.1
+/intarr    // 145
```

(updated for Swift 2.2, tested in Xcode Version 7.3)

Comment: One issue with this is that often (at least, when dealing with large arrays) you will need the sum to be a different type than the components. For instance, if you have a million UInt32s running the gamut from 0 to 2^32-1 (ex, populated by arc4random()), adding those up will overflow your UInt32 "sum" value every time.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

i had the same problem, i found on the documentation Apple this solution.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let addTwo: (Int, Int) -> Int = { x, y in x + y }
let numberSum = numbers.reduce(0, addTwo)
// 'numberSum' == 10
```

But, in my case i had a list of object, then i needed transform my value of my list:

```
let numberSum = self.list.map({$0.number_here}).reduce(0, { x, y in x + y })
```

this work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If your array contains nil then following solution will work for you

```
var array = [1,2,3,5,6,nil]
let sum = array.compactMap{$0}.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 2):

another easy way of getting it done:

```
let sumOfMultiples = ar.reduce(0) { x, y in x + y }          
print(sumOfMultiples)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple...

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0]
var n = 0
for i in array {
    n += i
}
print("My sum of elements is: \(n)")
```

Output:

> My sum of elements is: 37

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was like  this using property

```
    let blueKills = match.blueTeam.participants.reduce(0, { (result, participant) -> Int in
        result + participant.kills
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBOutlet var valueSource: [MultipleIntBoundSource]!

private var allFieldsCount: Int {
    var sum = 0
    valueSource.forEach { sum += $0.count }
    return sum
}
```

used this one for nested parameters

Answer (score -4):

For sum of elements in array of Objects

```
self.rankDataModelArray.flatMap{$0.count}.reduce(0, +)
```