# Swift - Getting the sum of looped int

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, core-data

Good day! I'm developing an app using Core Data, I want to get the sum of the "price" column in the database. I have this:

```
var myOrders : Array<AnyObject> = []

let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Shoes")
myOrders = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
```

And now to loop the data, I'm doing this.

```
for var i = 0; i < myOrders.count;i++ {

            var data: NSManagedObject = myOrders[i] as! NSManagedObject
            var price = data.valueForKey("Price") as? Int
            var sum = price.reduce(0, combine: +)

        }
```

But I'm getting an error `Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments`

How can I get the sum of the said colum. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is because:

1. your Optionals are not unwrapped properly
2. type Int has no "reduce" member
3. you're declaring `var sum` *inside* the loop, so its value is *replaced* at each iteration

Maybe use something like this instead:

```
var sum = 0

for order in myOrders {
    if let data = order as? NSManagedObject {
        if let price = data.valueForKey("Price") as? Int {
            sum += price
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have price as an Int. Trying to run reduce on a single value doesn't make any sense. You will need price to be an array of Ints.

Comment: I just tried this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795130/finding-sum-of-elements-in-swift-array. BTW, you can just comment. that is not an "Answer"

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your last line will work,

Do this with your for loop,

```
    var sum:Int?
    for var i = 0; i < myOrders.count;i++ {

        var data: NSManagedObject = myOrders[i] as! NSManagedObject
        var price:Int? = data.valueForKey("Price") as? Int
        sum = price! + sum

    }
```

Comment: Nope. doesn't work for me. I got and error: `'+=' is not a prefix unary operator`

Comment: let me check, I didn't tested that

Comment: No, It doesn't work. I tried  `println(sum)` it prints the 2 values