# Sum of Array containing custom class (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, sum, reduce

i am figuring out a way to get the sum of values of classes which are contained in an array. My setup is as follows:

```
class CustomClass {
    var value: Int?
    init(value: Int) {
       self.value = value
    }
}
```

---

```
let object1 = CustomClass(value: 2)
let object2 = CustomClass(value: 4)
let object3 = CustomClass(value: 8)

let array: [CustomClass] = [object1, object2, object3]
```

---

My current solution is as follows:

```
var sumArray = [Int]()
for object in array {
    sumArray.append(object.value!)
}
let sum = sumArray.reduce(0, +)
```

---

The problem is that it gets very complex with classes with many other values, does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: When you say

    "very complex with classes with many other values,"

Does this mean you are also trying to include values of different types of classes into the sum operation?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In fact my class contains Int and Date type but the date type is not supposed to be "merged"..

Comment: @AndreasSchultz I see nothing complex so far. You have to somehow convert the objects to a number (which you are already doing, although `.map` would be a better solution) and then just sum the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single `reduce` on `array`.

```
let sumOfValues = array.reduce({$0 += ($1.value ?? 0)})
```

Comment: There is no need to use reduce into for that. `reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value ?? 0) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, there's no _need_ to use `reduce(into:,_:)`, but I also don't see any advantage of using `reduce(_:,_:)` over it

Comment: There is but I not the right one to explain it to you. Before the implementation of the  `reduce(into:)` in Swift 4 people sometimes needed to declare the result as variable to be able to change it inside the closure. if you don't need to change it there just use plain reduce and return the sum  `result` plus the element.

Comment: Resuming If you use the plain reduce method there is no variables just constants inside your closure

Answer (score 12):

You can compactMap your array of custom class into array of integer and then reduce that array to its sum. Like,

```
let sum = array.lazy.compactMap { $0.value }
            .reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: use trailing closures, You can simplify to `.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: I would put a `lazy` in there, to skip the intermediate array allocation as a result of `compactMap`

Comment: @Alexander I wonder how to do that. Is it like `lazy var sum = array.compactMap { $0.value }.reduce(0, +)` ??

Comment: No no, the `lazy` attribute makes the expression computed upon first request. It still involves the intermediate array. Instead, you use the `lazy` computed property of the array, which returns a lazy view which keeps track of the operations you want to perform, without actually performing them until the result is needed. `array.lazy.compactMap { $0.value }.reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a protocol for your class or structures that contains a value. And change its declaration to non optional.

```
protocol Valueable {
    var value: Int { get }
}
```

Then you will need to make your class conform to that protocol:

```
class CustomClass: Valueable {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Now you can extend the collection protocol with a read only instance property to return the sum of all elements in your array.

```
extension Collection where Element: Valueable {
    var sum: Int {
        return reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
    }
}
```

---

```
let object1 = CustomClass(value: 2)
let object2 = CustomClass(value: 4)
let object3 = CustomClass(value: 8)

let objects = [object1, object2, object3]

let sum = objects.sum   // 14
```

---

**edit/update:**

Another option is to extend sequence and add a [generic sum method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046981/2303865) that accepts a key path that its property conforms to `AdditiveArithmetic`

---

or add an associated type to the protocol that conforms to AdditiveArithmetic:

```
protocol Valueable {
    associatedtype Value: AdditiveArithmetic
    var value: Value { get }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element: Valueable {
    var sum: Element.Value { reduce(.zero) { $0 + $1.value } }
}
```

---

```
class CustomClass: Valueable {
    let value: Decimal
    init(value: Decimal) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let object1 = CustomClass(value: 123.4567)
let object2 = CustomClass(value: 12.34567)
let object3 = CustomClass(value: 1.234567)

let objects = [object1, object2, object3]

let sum = objects.sum   // 137.036937
```

Comment: This is horribly complex, sorry.

Comment: @user3069232 Well this depends on your programing level. This is very basic protocol usage which is the main reason of Swift success (protocol oriented language)

Comment: @user3069232 another option is to extend sequence and add a [generic sum method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046981/2303865) that accepts a key path that its property conforms to `AdditiveArithmetic`

Comment: @user3069232 check my last edit. Thats when it start to get complex.

Answer (score 0):

Short way:

`let sum = customArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.intValue }`